# Combine/aggregate eclipse p2 repositories / extendable p2 repository

Tags: eclipse, repository, aggregation, tycho, p2

With maven/tycho build for [Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/) Eclipse plugin there is new p2 repository every release.

Release is done on [Bintray](https://bintray.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/) that does not allow to update files. So every version goes in its folder.

```
BaseFolder
BaseFolder/VersionFolder1
BaseFolder/VersionFolder2
BaseFolder/VersionFolder3
```

Is it possible to have `BaseFolder` prepared once as extendable p2 repository, and `VersionFolderN` added later?

So that there would be only one URL for updates and Eclipse platform could discover updates in the repository.

Comment: Found example of http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates/ is lists all versions of Eclipse Data Tools Platform (DTP) Project http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/ ( note that for users (http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates/1.11) URL s given)

Comment: Is there really no way you can edit the index files? If yes, there are only pretty hacky solutions which involve guessing all potential future releases.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are looking for is a composite p2 repository. You'll just need the following two files in the base folder:

- A `compositeContent.xml` with the following content:

  ```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <?compositeMetadataRepository version='1.0.0'?>
  <repository name='Project XYZ Releases Repository' type='org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository' version='1.0.0'>
      <properties size='1'>
          <property name='p2.atomic.composite.loading' value='true'/>
      </properties>
      <children size='3'>
          <child location='VersionFolder1'/>
          <child location='VersionFolder2'/>
          <child location='VersionFolder3'/>
      </children>
  </repository>
  ```
- A `compositeArtifacts.xml` with the following, similar content:

  ```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <?compositeArtifactRepository version='1.0.0'?>
  <repository name='Project XYZ Releases Repository' type='org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepository' version='1.0.0'>
      <properties size='0'>
      </properties>
      <children size='3'>
          <child location='VersionFolder1'/>
          <child location='VersionFolder2'/>
          <child location='VersionFolder3'/>
      </children>
  </repository>
  ```

When a new version is released, just add the new folder as child in both files.

The two files may also be compressed as ZIP and named `compositeContent.jar` and `compositeArtifacts.jar` to save network bandwidth. However this makes editing the files a little less practical.

The Eclipse simultaneous release repositories also use this approach. E.g., at the time of writing this, the [Eclipse Luna repository](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna) contains only the original release and SR 1 (see [compositeContent](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/compositeContent.jar), [compositeArtifacts](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/compositeArtifacts.jar)). SR 2 will be added later, so that users will be able to get updates without having to configure a new repository URL.

Comment: this is superb solution for the problem. Should all `VersionFolder` exist from the very beginning? Can `compositeContent.jar` and `compositeArtifacts.jar` be together `artifacts.jar` and `content.jar` with in the same folder http://dl.bintray.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse/ ?

This is questions for my research now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Wonderland! This example already works! `https://raw.github.com/Enide/eclipse-p2-composite-repository/master/`

Comment: If you put the `compositeContent/Artifacts.jar` and the `content/artifacts.jar` into the same folder, p2/Tycho will only consider either. By default, only the the latter would be used.