# Redirect for Eclipse p2 repository (update site)

Tags: eclipse, redirect, repository, p2

How to configure requests to a p2 repository (an update site) to go to anther URL?

Comment: You can do this in a number of ways, depending on your environment and scenario. Can you describe more precisely?

Comment: I have just learned today that composite repositories can redirect (combine from other site) as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951842/combine-aggregate-eclipse-p2-repositories-extendable-p2-repository? So this question becomes duplicate. Please add other options if they are .

Comment: I find your question quite vague. It is not quite clear what is your scenario. Depending on what you need you may use: hosts file, proxy and/or network configuration, hacking p2 api etc... Pls describe more precisely what do you want to achieve.