# Tycho | How to build multiple version of same plugin using tycho

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have a plugin which contains other plugins and feature projects.

I am able to build plugin using tycho and I am getting deliverable in eclipsepluginupdateSite\target in zip format which is working fine for single version of eclipse.

Now I am facing error how to configure tycho for to build multiple version of same plugin?

In manual process I am following below steps:

For example I want to create a plugin with version 4.8.800 along with(4.6.612,4.7.711) versions

1. Delete eclipsepluignupdatesite features, plugins, artifacts.jar and content.jar
2. Copy previous versions features, plugins, artifacts.jar and content.jar in eclipsepluignupdatesite (e.g. previous version plugin is 4.6.612,4.7.711)
3. Use export wizard for build plugins.
4. Now In eclipsepluginupdatesite I found  features, plugins, artifacts.jar and content.jar with contains plugin version 4.6.612,4.7.7.711 and also 4.8.800

I copied whole eclipsepluginupdate contents under a host server url.
When I use that url to install plugin It shows me three category 4.6,4.7,4.8 
Under each category I have plugin 4.6.3.612, 4.7.0.711, 4.8.0.800 and I can install any plugin.

sample screen shots

[image: Multiple version plugin]![enter image description here]

Using tycho I am able to build single plugin but I am not getting how to build plugin along with previous plugins using tycho.
Please help me out

Answer (score 3):

[Currently](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=403481), it is not possible to build a p2 repository with multiple versions of plug-ins (unless these plug-ins are non-singletons and could also be installed at once).

But what you can do is to build a p2 repository for each version separately, and later join these repositories together through a composite repository. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951842/combine-aggregate-eclipse-p2-repositories-extendable-p2-repository) has an answer with an example of how to do this.