# What Is the Correct Way to Create an Update for an Eclipse Feature

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I previously created a plug-in for the Eclipse IDE, and now want to create an update (new version) for it. I cannot seem to find many resources describing the "correct" process to do this - everything is about the initial creation of the site.

Specifically, there appear to be options to create "feature patch" projects, options to change the version number (in the original feature project), and manual options to change the version on the update site (in the update site project).

In the past, when I manually updated the version numbers, the site has behaved strangely, acting like the previous plug-in version never existed.

The end result I want is for people pointing at my update site to be notified (if auto-update is configured) that a new version is available, and for the "version history" of the plug-in to be maintained (within the limits of what eclipse update sites are configurable to maintain)

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20951842/1700321.

Comment: Thanks! This will definitely be useful, as I plan on using Bintray in the future to host the site - however I'm still wondering if there is an accepted "correct" way/pattern to use when developing a plug-in within Eclipse to go about creating an update. If not, this is a great alternative!